# How can I share image between two websites?

Tags: php, server

Two websites are running on one server, so let's say it A.com and B.com. Their document root directory is different of course. The problem is when I upload image on A.com, I should show it on B.com too.
How can I solve this?

I don't want to link from one site to another. I should use image in generating PDF and link is not working.

Comment: Put the url from `A.com\image.jpg` in `B.com`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Of course, I know using link.
What I am concerning is use it in path.
I should use that image in generating PDF.
And it requires path.
link is not working.

Comment: It should work.Can you show us the code?

Comment: Given the brevity of the answers and the lack of detail in the question, I am voting to delete this question. I am pleased it was helpful to the question author, but I don't think it will be of much use in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use full path in your code!!! It must work or check permission.

Comment: It works. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the url's for both site example if u you need an file from **a.com in b.com** just call
**a.com/your_file_path**

Let me know if there is any confusion